# Push notification in blackberry 10 cascades

Tags: blackberry-10

i need to do push notification in blackberry 10 cascades,if i close the application means can't able to show my notification in the Blackberry Hub

here is the code

```
    Button{
    notification.body="hai notification testing " 
    notification.notify();
    Notification {
                    id: notification
                    title: "Title"
                }
    }
```

when the user closes the application means means,i need to show the notification in Blackberry Hub 
How to do this , can anyone send me some solutions to solve this.?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been solved here : http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Cascades-Development/Push-Notification-in-Blackberry-Hub/m-p/2186999/highlight/true#M15290

here's the code for notifications including invoke from hub

```
Notification notification;
n.setTitle(tr("Your title"));
n.setBody(tr("your detailed description"));
n.setCategory("vibrate");

InvokeRequest request;
request.setTarget("org.xyz.yourapp.invoke");
request.setMimeType("application/vnd.yourapp");
n.setInvokeRequest(request);
n.notify();
```

and inside your bar descriptor you need

```
<!-- Have an invoke entry here for when a notification is clicked on in the BlackBerry Hub -->
<!-- This will cause the application to be opened -->
<invoke-target id="org.xyz.yourapp.invoke">
    <type>APPLICATION</type>
    <filter>
        <action>bb.action.OPEN</action>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.yourapp</mime-type>
    </filter>
</invoke-target>
```

and dont forget to set permissions

```
<permission>run_when_backgrounded</permission>
<permission>post_notification</permission>
```